# Mongodb server is not running

Tags: mongodb

Previously when I dbl click mongod file mongodb server was started. But recently when I dbl click the same file it doesn't stand, only comes and disappear within fraction of seconds. If any one  know the cause pls tell me the cause.

Comment: check mongodb logs

Comment: Start it from command line or even better as a service.